# Run arg based on condition

Tags: java, xml, ant

I want to run specific `<arg>` tags based on a condition. Also my ANT version is 1.8.2 so I can't use if and unless.

I have several `<arg>`'s in my `<exec>` and I only want certain `<arg>`'s to run if certain conditions are met, in my case if my ${host.NAME} equals specified servers.

e.g.

```xml
<condition property="validHost" value="${dynamicValue}"> (except not dynamic, the first value is repeated for all instances)
    <or>
        <equals arg1="${host.NAME}" arg2="example" />
        <equals arg1="${host.NAME}" arg2="example" />
    </or>
</condition>

<exec...>
    <arg line="always runs"/> (Always runs)
    <arg line="${validHost}"/> (Only runs if validHost condition true)
</exec>
```

The problem is that when I put a dynamic value inside of the `<condition value="${dynamicValue}">` tag, it sets every iteration as the first value instead of dynamically changing it. For example these values:

value1=Hello
value2=World

will result in

arg1=Hello
arg2=Hello

When I echo the dynamic value itself changes so I assume the `<condition>` tag isn't called dynamically instead is immutable. Is there any way I can work around this besides updating?

Comment: Why would this condition be getting set multiple times? Are you running this in a for loop?

Comment: By default Ant properties are global and can only be set once. To make them only visible within the scope of a target (and thus settable each time th etarget is executed), you need to declare them with `<local name="dynamicValue" />`. See [local](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/local.html) for reference.